# Paper.js pathData animation onFrame and onMouseDrag

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, paperjs

I have created a line using `pathData` method [[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/cnL1owkw/) ]. I want the line animate a small wave effect in `onFrame` function. Also, the line would be rubberband effect when it `onMouseDrag` function and it will return back to the original shape when `onMouseUp` function. I'm a newbie in [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), so when I write some codes I get the animation with losing the object shape. check below codes

**Codes Updated**

```
var amount = 55;
var center = view.center;

function onFrame(event) {
    // Loop through the segments of the path:
    for (var i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
        var path = linePath;
        var segment = path.segments[i];

        // A cylic value between -1 and 1
        var sinus = Math.sin(event.time * 3 + i);

        // Change the y position of the segment point:
        segment.point.y = sinus * 1 + center.y;
    }
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
   var location = linePath.getNearestLocation(event.point);
   var segment = location.segment;
   var point = segment.point;
   if (!point.fixed && location.distance < 600 / 4) {
      var y = event.point.y;
      point.y += (y - point.y) / 6;
      if (segment.previous && !segment.previous.fixed) {
        var previous = segment.previous.point;
        previous.y += (y - previous.y) / 24;
      }
      if (segment.next && !segment.next.fixed) {
        var next = segment.next.point;
        next.y += (y - next.y) / 24;
      }
    }
 }
```

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/cnL1owkw/8/) ^^

Any paperJs experts please help me to achieve it. Helping would be appreciated , Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the problem with the wave effect. You're only transforming along the Y-axis. Which can be what you want, but I'm assuming, it isn't.

Usually, the effect will look a lot better if the line is transformed along the [normal vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)) of the line. The normal would be direction perpendicular to the direction of the line. So, when you transform, it looks like the wave is travelling along the line itself.

Calculating the normal in 2D is easy, because you just need to reflect the current direction on a single plane.

```
var deltaX = nextSegment.point.x - segment.point.x;
var deltaY = nextSegment.point.y - segment.point.y;
var length = Math.sqrt( deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY );

var normal = [ deltaX / length, deltaY / length ];
normal = [ normal[ 1 ], -normal[ 0 ] ];
```

We can now use that normal to transform the line:

```
toManipulate.point.x = segment.point.x + normal[0] * sinus * 3;
toManipulate.point.y = segment.point.y + normal[1] * sinus * 3;
```

You can have a look at it in [my fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq4ygujx/).

Another key aspect is, you don't want to transform your original data. Which is why I created another copy:

```
var linePathCached = new Path(dataLine);
var linePath = new Path(dataLine);
```

You're going to always need a copy of your original data, so that you can manipulate a copy and use the old data for a new transformation in the next frame.

Now, second, your rubber band effect.

You're already pretty close with your current code. But, again, you're transforming your original data, which is not helpful.

For this effect, I would suggest creating a second copy of your original data, bringing you to 3 data sets:

1. Your original line path, which you use as a basis for all transformations.
2. The line path that is manipulated by dragging with the mouse.
3. The line path you're rendering.

In your `onMouseDrag` handler, you would transform your set 2.

In your `onFrame` handler, you would apply the sinus wave transformation you already have on set 2 and produce set 3. Additionally, you would interpolate all segments between their current position and their original position in set 1.

You can apply the very common [elasticOut equation](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js#L100), or look into [other](http://matthaeuskrenn.com/springto/) spring-related implementations.

Comment: you have created a copy of original line path for manipulate the wave effect, I'm little bit confused that the original copy is the basis for all transformation , the first copy is the wave effect in the onFrame handler and second copy the 3rd data set that is manipulated by dragging with the mouse, and then what is "3.The line path you're rendering.". Is it the right way or could you clear little simple way.@oliver

Comment: @Krish I updated the fiddle to illustrate what I meant. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now :) https://jsfiddle.net/uq4ygujx/2/

Comment: @Krish Because it was so much fun, I went ahead and also adjusted your `onDrag` to use the actual direction vector of the drag for the operation. It's still not perfect, but I hope you'll *make* it perfect ;) https://jsfiddle.net/uq4ygujx/3/ Cheers

Comment: This is incredible you are such a brilliant coder ever. I don't know how to express thanks but you deserved (y) :) @oliver

Comment: And one thing we don't need third party easing implementation? also Is it possible to support magnet effect in paperJS like this http://bl.ocks.org/sxv/4491174

Comment: Well, you can use a different easing method instead of the `lerp` function I used. It depends on the style you want to achieve. I don't see why that effect wouldn't be possible in PaperJS, but this is the first time I used it ;D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110380/discussion-between-krish-and-oliver-salzburg).